# Tell rspec (core) that test is testing controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Trying to run this test but keep getting the following error:

```
Failure/Error: get :index

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::TestModuleTestController::Controller:0x007fa4bc120d00>
```

**Note: I'm not using rspec-rails.**

```
require "spec_helper"

module TestModule
  describe TestController, :type => :controller do
    describe "controller" do
      it "sets X-Frame-Options to ALLOWALL" do
        get :index
        expect(response.headers['X-Frame-Options']).to eq('ALLOWALL')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: please make sure you've included require 'rails_helper' in your file.

Comment: From what I understood, rails_helper is specific to rspec-rails. I'm not using that, if I try and require rails_helper I get an error that the file cannot be found.

Comment: can you please post spec_helper file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: I'm not using rspec-rails.

That's your problem right there. All the rails type specs (controller, request, features, views) are part of rspec-rails not rspec-core.

Without rspec-rails the `type` metadata does absolutely nothing - its just a plain example group describing a class.

The solution is to add rspec-rails to your gemfile.

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.6'
end
```

And run `rails g rspec install`.

- https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails